# Materialize Datepicker change "datepicker-date-display"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, modal-dialog, materialize

So I'm wondering if there's a way to edit the default "datepicker-date-display"?

I know we can set the i18n options for the language but in some languages the default date display would be; "Sat, 5 Jan" instead of the default "Sat, Jan 5".

So I would like to swap the day and month around in this case..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the "format" field in the options parameters to something like this:

```
const options = {
    format: "ddd, mmm d"
};
```

That should make the datepicker always use the format you requested (day of week, month in short form and date without leading 0).